# How to POST jQuery variables to PHP in same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**Both** my **jQuery** code **and** **PHP** code are **in the same PHP file** (not two separate files).

I want to POST jQuery Variable to the PHP code.

But it Shows some errors ("undefined index") when running the PHP file.

**PHP file is as follows** (test.php).

```
<?php 
    $country = $_POST['userCountry'];
    $ip = $_POST['userIp'];

    echo $country;
    echo $ip;
?>

<html>
<head><title></title>
    <script src = "jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
            var country = data.country_name;
            var ip = data.ip;

            $.ajax({
                method:"POST",
                url:"test.php",
                data:{userCountry:country, userIp:ip}
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: @icecub, First argument for `getJSON` is URL which is passed in above example..

Comment: Your URL of page and passed in `getJSON` are different..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $country = $_POST['userCountry'];
    $ip = $_POST['userIp'];

    echo $country;
    echo $ip;
}
?>

<html>
<head><title></title>
    <script src = "jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
            var country = data.country_name;
            var ip = data.ip;
            $.ajax({
                method:"POST",
                url:"test.php",
                data:{userCountry:country, userIp:ip},
                success:function(result){
                    $('body').html(result);
                }

            });
           });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Try this code. Just Tested OK

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the wanted result...
But it looks like it. So try this:

**(EDITED)**

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="result1"></div>
<br>
<div id="result2"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var country;
    var ip;

    $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
        country = data.country_name;
        ip = data.ip;
        console.log(country+" "+ip);

        $("#result1").append(country);
        $("#result2").html(ip);
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Notice that there is no PHP or $.ajax... Only $getJSON.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But php has to be there for further implementations. However this will be useful later..

Comment: Ok... With this, you could "play" a little with the result, organise, format, etc... Then send it to a PHP page. BTW, thank for making me discover usefull this link (freegeoip). ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's because PHP compiles on the server while jQuery compiles on client. You kept both in the same file. So by the time ajax runs PHP has already been compiled thus giving you the message undefined . Make a separate file for PHP part or use the `isset()` and refresh the page using jQuery once the data has been submitted.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Your advice will be helpful in later implementations.